# How to add a span tag to a variable inside a .html Jquery method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a difficult time finding out why this code doesn't work. Specifically, why I can't span the variable, and then add to it a class? Of course, I succeed in adding the class if it's just text, and not a variable.:

```
var fruit = 'bananas';
var paragraph = $('<div></div>');

paragraph.html('I like ' + '<span class="features">'fruit'</span>');
$(".features").css("color","yellow");
```

Comment: How does it not work? What is happening? What should be happening? Are there any errors?

Comment: Looks like a syntax error, needs a `+` on either side of `fruit`

Comment: @RobinZigmond You got it. I can't believe that was all I was missing. Hours and hours and hours spent on THAT. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things I can see that is wrong with your code.

```
// fruit var is fine
var fruit = 'bananas';

// originally you had html markup in here, but you have to use html selectors.
var paragraph = $('div');

// you were close here but you didnt have plus symbols either side of your fruit var
paragraph.html('I like '+'<span class="features">'+fruit+'</span>');

// add the colour to your .features span - this is fine
$(".features").css("color","yellow");
```

See working fiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/k0vrs8ne/

Comment: That was exactly it! Thank you! Those blasted plus symbols... I appreciate the link to the jsfiddle!.